# gitlab check a user permission

Tags: git, command-line, permissions, gitlab

I am using git from gitLab. I would like to check **the permission of specific user**. 
The user is not able to clone the repository and on web the user is listed as developer but from the command line is getting the **http error code 403**

I would therefore like to know if he has the puller/ clone permission. how do I do it from the commandline?

so far I have not found a useful command

Answer (score 1):

When cloning over HTTPS (as opposed to SSH) GitLab has no way of figuring out the identity of the person cloning the repository. Thus, you can grant a developer all the permissions you want, but since GitLab simply doesn't know who is trying to clone the repository, it refuses.

There's a couple of solutions to this problem:

1. (probably **not** what you want): Set the repository's visibility to public. This way, *everyone* can clone your repository.
2. Tell your developer to [add an SSH key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/) to their account and have them clone the repository from the SSH URL instead. This way, GitLab can actually identify them and grant them permission to clone the repository.

As for your original question, probably the easiest way to examine whether or not a user has clone rights for a repository is to just try it.